# How do I add a referral variable to an AddThis URL without resetting the count?

Tags: addthis

for my project I need to be able to add a referral variable (something like ?ref=xxxx) to URLs shared via AddThis.

However, by adding the variable and changing the URL, the "count" displayed on the tool resets .

So does anyone out there have a solution to use AddThis to share URLs with variables on them, without resetting the "count" displayed to the user?

Thank you all so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

So, you can use `fb_ref` parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

In the AddThis you need to use the following format: `fb:like:fb_ref`

AddThis Support ticket: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/1127049-facebook-data-ref

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the `ref` attribute on the Like button. See the `ref` attribute here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

However, I'm currently looking for how to implement this via `AddThis`. I'll post here if/when I find a solution.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? I have similar problem